# Find a closed formula for $ \sum _{k=0}^n k^2 5^k $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I need help with the following problem.

$$ \sum _{k=0}^n k^2 5^k $$

Comment: Did you try something yourself?

Comment: it's unclear https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @kingW3, could I see the sum k^2 and 5^k separately and use different properties? I know that $$sum {k=0}^n x^k= x^(n+1)-1/(x-1). I know that far. Can I substitute for x for x and then multiply the result to the the recurrence formula of sum {k=0)^n k^2?

Answer (score 2):

Key word: "generating function".

Hint: Start with $$f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n t^k.$$You can give a closed-form expression for $f$ since it's just a geometric series.

So differentiating gives a closed form for $$f'(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n kt^{k-1}.$$Multiply both sides of *that* by $t$ and you have $\sum_{k=0}^n kt^k$. Now you're exactly halfway there.

Comment: I like differentiating with respect to $5$

Comment: @RossMillikan That's probably quicker and simpler - being a mathematician I prefer a harder approach.